# Design a priority_queue C++

Tags: c++11, stl

**Objective** : Design a priority_queue:

**Problem** : How to use reference as argument of my constructor.

**Current Implementation:** [Stub] Will compile if algorithm, vector and functional are included. I do not claim it as mine. I read somewhere as to how it is implemented and then tried re-creating from memory.

```
template <typename T,class container = std::vector<T>,
 class cmp std::less<T> >                                                                 
          class priority_queue{                                                                                                                                  
              public:                                                                    
                  explicit priority_queue(container c = container(),                     
                          cmp x = cmp()):                                                
                      cx(c),                                                             
                      cm(x)                                                              
                         {                                                               
                             std::make_heap(cx.begin(), cx.end(), cm);                   
                         }  
                private:     
                          container cx;                                                          
                          cmp cm;
```

This works.

However, the following is what I desire.

```
priority_queue(container &c = container(),                     
                              cmp &x = cmp())
```

This is to avoid the rvalue getting initialized with as container() and then getting copied to "c" which is later copied to cx.

If I do not specify a default value, everything will work.

Comment: You can't bind *r-value* to *l-value* reference. Try `const container& c = container{}`

Comment: Also note that using heap is not a perfect solution, as heap is not stable, while the elements  inserted to priority queue should be stable, even if they compare equal. In my RTOS I've implemented things like that with linked lists.

Comment: @Zereges, would that not make my 'c' immutable?

Comment: @FreddieChopin, I did not think of that.  By linked list, do you mean to say a BST?

Comment: In the RTOS - due to the fact that the lists are generally short - I've just used plain-old double linked lists. But any structure which keeps the insertion order would be OK.

Comment: @FreddieChopin. I see that makes sense. I am not sure how C++ STL implements priority queue with std::vector<> as the container. Will look this up now. I thought a heap is how it is done by default.

Comment: @user6184793 It would, but just only for few moments, since `c` will perish at the end of constructor call and its contents will be copied to `cx` class member variable.

Comment: Having a parameter of `const container& c = container{}` would indeed render `c` immutable - but why do you care? You don't mutate `c`, you mutate `cx`. Constness doesn't magically transfer to it when it's initialized from `c`.

Comment: Anyway, what's wrong with [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)? Is there a reason you are trying to roll your own?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, learning purposes. I have used these containers for years but I realized I have never needed to roll my own. I do not mean to use them on production, but it is a nice to have knowledge. I plan to implement, unordered_map, unordered_set, set, multiset next. Here's the priority queue and it works. https://github.com/suranapranay/stl-design. It is all about going through the motions of designing it.